# htaccess mask to fake directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm not sure if this has been asked, because I've been searching and just not finding the right answer, unless I am blind.

We have a site on a machine www.example.com/?webform, which we want to mask to a fake directory that doesn't exist. Aka: www.example.com/blahblah

I don't know if I am making this overly complicated in the .htaccess file, but what I have so far is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} webform
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/blahblah [L,R=301]
```

Is this correct? Or am I missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and it works

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blahblah?      [NC]
RewriteRule .*  /?webform                   [L]
```

The above code maps:
    **http://test.mi-creativity.com/blahblah**

to this:
    **http://test.mi-creativity.com/?page4**

you can open the two links to make sure.

Comment: I'm not sure if this worked. I am starting to wonder if it is something in apache that is blocking this.

Comment: Still no go. The one thing I am curious about is we have a redirect in place to redirect port 80 to 443, would that redirect over right a second redirect?